# How to prevent a crash in a plugin from affecting main program (dlopen)

Tags: c++, linux, plugins, error-handling, dlopen

I'm making a plugin-system with 'dlopen' in linux. theres a central application that transfers data(JSON) between plugins.
We can handle throwed exceptions using try-catch clause. My question is about errors that terminates the program, like Segmentation fault. How can i prevent a Segmentation fault in one of plugins from terminating the whole application?

Can i do something with fork? I've never used fork and i donno if i can transfer data between forked process and main process?
Or i cant use dlopen fr such a thing and i've to use another method ?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't separate signal handling easily, if at all.  Signal handlers are process-wide, so even if you used `sigsetjmp/siglongjmp` to handle SIGSEGV in your code, for example, you've still impacted entire process - along with having the entire process impact your code.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK The only way to be safe is to run the plugins in serparate 
processes and communicate with them over pipes or sockets etc.

you're using json so your data is already serialized, you'll need to write a loader that dlopens the the plugin and deals with the pre-exisitng sockets..

Comment: yeah, im thinking of sockets too. i was just wanted to see if theres a way around signals ...

Comment: out of band signaling is possible on sockets. I'm not sure on the details.